# Backed up over wrong hard drive

Tags: hard-disk, data-recovery, cat, dm-crypt, pv

I've just written over the wrong hard drive using the command:

```
sudo sh -c 'pv /dev/sdb >/dev/sdc'
```

How do I go about undoing this?

I was creating the first even backup of the drive, and I backed up over the wrong drive...  The drive which got written over also has no backups, I was going to backup that drive next.

Both drives were dm-crypt'ed.

Comment: Recover from backups.

Comment: @Mat, Not possible, because I was creating a backup of the drive for the first time, and it went wrong.  i.e. I backed up over the wrong drive.  The drive which got written over also has no back ups.  I was going to backup that drive next...

Comment: There's practically no chance you will be able to recover that data. Take this as a learning experience, don't expend too much energy trying to do the impossible.

Comment: "There is no undo. Especially not with encryption involved." exactly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do not have backups, your data wasn't important.

It's gone. There is no undo. Especially not with encryption involved.

`something that produces output > /dev/somedisk` overwrites data on the device. Whatever is overwritten can not be restored, so your only chance would be if you noticed and cancelled it right away. Then probably only the first few hundred megs would be missing and you might have a chance at recovery, especially if the partitions you want to recover started somewhere further out. In this case it's a matter of restoring the partition table, from memory or using `testdisk`, `gpart` or whatever.

If you did not cancel, it depends on how much output was produced, i.e. in your case whether `/dev/sdb` was smaller than `/dev/sdc` so it was only overwritten so far.

However, you say it was dm-crypt'ed. That usually means LUKS. And LUKS has a header at the start. If you lose that header and the LUKS container is not still open, there is no way to get anything back. If it's still open, you want to save the output of `dmsetup table --showkeys`.

Some people use LUKS without partitioning the drive, and then have some silly mistake in a partitioner or installer that does nothing but create a small partition table. That overwrites less than 512 bytes at the start of the disk but it's still enough to damage the LUKS header and the data is irrecoverably lost.

Comment: > If you do not have backups, your data wasn't important.   That's not true.  My data was important, I tried creating a backup, and messed up the process.  If the data was not important, I would not have tried to back up the drives, and I probably would still have the data...

Comment: It was supposed to imply that if you do not have backups, your data is already lost, even if you don't know it yet. Be it hardware failure or user error, without backups you just can't recover from anything, and if you can not recover your data is good as gone. The storage that never fails and never forgets data has not been invented yet. If your data is important to you, you have to have backups of it, from the very beginning.

Answer (score 1):

No way to recover, as simple as that.

As a side note, doing `dd` is not a perfect way to backup files.
For future cases, consider using tools like [`dar`](http://dar.linux.free.fr/) - you want some compression, incremental backup would also allow you to save huge amount of time and disk space in most cases.

Comment: `dd` can be the right choice in some situations - you just better know what you are doing. There is no perfect way to backup files. I use `dar` myself but consider it far from perfect. It's complicated to use and some parts of it just don't work well (`dar_manager` doesn't scale).

Comment: Obviously, this was meant to be just a brief notice, not a deep (and OT) analysis of backup tools ;)
However, I cannot think of general use cases where `cat /dev/sdX > /dev/sdY` would not be better than `df` - the latter one is becoming a very specialized tool these days (e.g. zeroing boot sector comes to my mind).

Comment: Compressing an encrypted container would be pointless. `cat` would be faster than `dd`.